# Explanation of the Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation

This is a section from Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra book:
[image]

Although I understand the uniqueness and existence of that matrix, I am having trouble understanding what he means by, "The only such polynomial that vanishes at... No other polynomial of degree $n-1$ can have $n$ roots." What does he mean by vanishing and why does no other polynomial have $n$ roots?

Comment: the uniqueness and the existence of the matrix is because it's written there. Nothing more to it

Comment: A special property of the polynomial is that it allows you to determine $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$ from $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ by taking the inverse. Now you might be curious as to why this matrix is invertible in the first place. One way to see this is by computing the determinant and noting it is not 0.

Comment: Another reason is to note: (after convincing yourself that a solution indeed exists for the system of equation) if there were two polynomials $p(x),q(x)$ with degree $n-1$, with coefficients $x_i$ and $y_i$ resp. then $(p-q)(z)=\sum (x_i-y_i)z^{i-1}$ will have $n$ zeros. An $n$ degree polynomial can have at most $n$ zeros unless the polynomial is uniformly $0$. Therefore, $(p-q)(z)=0$ uniformly and so the solution is unique. This might be what the book was trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that the polynomial $P(t)=x_1+x_2t+\ldots+x_nt^{n-1}$ *vanishes* at some point $t=t_0$ if $t_0$ is a "root" or a "zero" of that polynomial, i.e. if $P(t_0)=0$.

What the author is trying to say is that *a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ can have at most $n-1$ different zeros* (barring the case where the polynomial itself is a zero polynomial - i.e. all its coefficients are zero and therefore it "vanishes" everywhere). This result is a well-known result from algebra, and is a consequence of unique factorization for polynomials.